# Nested Radon-Nikodym Derivative

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\pi$ and $\eta$ be two measures on the same measurable space $(E, \mathcal{E})$ and that $\pi\ll\eta$ so the Radon-Nikodym derivative exists
$$
\frac{d \pi}{d \eta} = \rho
$$
*Assuming all regularity conditions necessary* (e.g. $\pi \ll \lambda$ and $\eta \ll \lambda$) can I say
$$
\frac{d \pi}{d \eta} = \frac{\displaystyle \frac{d\pi}{d \lambda}}{\displaystyle \frac{d \eta}{d\lambda}} = \frac{\rho_\pi}{\rho_\eta}
$$
where $\rho_\pi$ and $\rho_\eta$ are the densities of $\pi$ and $\eta$ respectively with respect to $\lambda$?

Comment: I think you are essentially asking about the chain rule; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2558790/43949) for instance.

Comment: @angryavian The chain rule is a bit different though! Followinge chain rule I would have
$$
\frac{d \pi}{d \eta} = \frac{d \pi}{d \lambda} \cdot \frac{d \lambda}{d \eta}
$$
So unless I can show / prove that (under some regularity conditions)
$$
\frac{d \lambda}{d \eta} = \left(\frac{d \eta}{d \lambda}\right)^{-1}
$$
then those formulas are different

Comment: If you assume all the measures are mutually absolutely continuous ($\sigma$-finite etc) then by taking $\pi=\eta$ you get $1=\frac{d\eta}{d\lambda}\cdot\frac{d\lambda}{d\eta}$ (the fact that $1=\frac{d\eta}{d\eta}$ is clear from the definition).

Comment: The identity that you want to show, $d\pi/d\eta = (d\pi/d\lambda)/(d\eta/d\lambda)$ is equivalent to $d\pi/d\lambda = (d\pi/d\eta)/(d\eta/d\lambda),$ which is exactly the chain rule if $\pi\ll\eta\ll\lambda.$

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you! Do you have a reason as to why the two radon nikodym derivatives are the same?

Comment: I accidentally copied the division slash. It should read $d\pi/d\lambda = (d\pi/d\eta)(d\eta/d\lambda).$