# Relating two measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a positive ($f> 0$) Lebesgue integrable function. Then we define a new measure $\nu$ as follows:
$$
\nu(E) = \int_{E} f \, dx.
$$
Is it true that
$$
m(E) = \int_{E} \frac{1}{f} \,d\nu.
$$
I am suspeccting this because $d\nu = f \, dx$ so we can write as $dx = f^{-1} \, d\nu$. If this is not correct then how can we "invert" and write $m$ in terms of $\nu$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2558790/694754

Comment: Just plug it in and try out what the resulting measure is.